# Add one to a character in haskell

Tags: haskell

How could I add a number to a character. For example if I say A+1 I want to get B and so on. Especially I would like to write a function to get the successor of a tuple `(char,char,char)`. For example `myfunc (A,B,C)` would be `(A,B,D)` and so on.

Any standard way to do this in haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the suggestion by @behzad.nouri, you could do something like this:

```
myfunc :: (Char, Char, Char) -> (Char, Char, Char)
myfunc (x,y,z) = (x,y,succ z)
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at [`Data.Char`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Data-Char.html). The `ord` and `chr` functions are what you're after. Perhaps something like:

```
nextChar :: Char -> Char
nextChar x = chr $ ord x + 1
```

Comment: `Char` is an instance of [`Enum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) which means you may simply call [`succ`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ) instead of redefining it

Comment: Agree with @behzad.nouri here. If you want to see how that works, check out [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#succ). `toEnum . (+ 1)  . fromEnum` :)